# Is it possible to get the route network from Android Google Map?

Tags: android, google-maps

I am trying to find a way to get the map of the road network currently visible on the the screen, while using the Google Maps API v2 for Android. I want to place some markers along roads, but I don't know if that is even possible? I can get the addresses, or the path between two addresses(using the route manager), but I need to know if I can paths of...all the roads visible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That want you want, is to get the route as vectors (as poly line of latitude, longitude) coordinates.

But, No you can't. (although there is an inofficial Google API that gest the route as coded and compressed vector, but the usage is not legal.)

The vectors are "owned" by TeleAtlas/TomTom and they are not public availble, nor has Google the right to give them out.
If you need vectors, then you have to use OpenStreetMap routing Service, which potentzally provides vectors of a route (via an OpenStreetmap API)